# how to retrieve field values from python-bugzilla xml-rpc

Tags: python, web-services, xml-rpc, bugzilla

I am using ”[python-bugzilla 0.8.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-bugzilla)” for xml-rpc web service of bugzilla 4.2.

Anyone knows how to retrieve field values. i.e. 
If bugzilla Severity field have following values: Critical, Significant, Medium, Uncritical etc. then how I can get these values via python code ?

getbugfields() method returns the names of the fields but how I could get the values of the fields ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reply from "redhat" (supplier of python-bugzilla tool) that

"*there is no wrapper for what I want. The bugzilla XMLRPC call is 'fields' for bugzilla4+

http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/api/Bugzilla/WebService/Bug.html#fields

It can be a work around this by accessing the xmlrpc proxy directly and handling
the calls yourself, ex:

```
import bugzilla
bz = bugzilla.Bugzilla(url="https://bugzilla.kernel.org")

print bz._proxy.Bug.fields({"names" : ["rep_platform"]})
```

Of course, that's not supported, so it could stop working on you one day, but
for personal scripts and stuff it's an alternative.*"